# Getting value of a class with getAttribute method

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm looking for a way to get the value of the class (for my example "AAABC") stored in a variable. I tried different key words with the `getAttribute` method, but none were successful. Key word "class" obviously gave me "gwt-Label", all the other key words gave me "null".
Using `getAttribute` is not necessary, if you can think of an other elegant way.

Example:

```
<div class="gwt-Label">AAABC</div>
```

Comment: update HTML code with some more data. Above and Below classes, Which can be use to locate Xpath with nested structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gwt-Label']")).getText();

This is solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do the following to get the string from your class object:-

```
 String example = object.toString();
 // here in msg you will get the whole string < div class="gwt-Label"> AAABC< /div>
```

Now you can use approach like below to get your string:-

```
  example = example.substring(example.indexOf(">") + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* to retrieve the **class** *attribute* you can use the following line of code :

```
String myClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='AAABC']")).getAttribute("class");
```

Comment: This stores "borderMainContent" in my variable. That's not the string I expected.

Comment: @Runningstack Does the _HTML_ contains the text **AAABC** some where else as well? Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.